# How to count the members of a queue in Flow

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, visual-workflow

In a flow I have the Queue Id, I want to count the number of users in that queue in the flow. Is it possible?

Comment: Queues can include public groups as members and your lookup will not include users added due to membership in the public group. This makes this quite difficult to calculate unless your queues only contain users. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_groupmember.htm

Answer (score 2):

You can query the `GroupMember` object and filter out records based on `GroupId`. Then you can iterate over the records that you retrieved and store the count in a variable.

Comment: In an assignment element you can set a Number variable to the size of the collection using the equals count operator.